# How printing looks in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to change the way something will look when printing?

I have a set of reports that is being managed by a webapp and I want to have them be available for printing. However, they look terrible when it actually comes to printing. It seems like my options are either do the question above or make a printing specific page. I would prefer to do the alternate printing look for ease of use.

Comment: How are the reports created? Are they HTML, Crystal Reports....

Comment: dynamically created from a DB with html

Comment: @AlexRohr If it's HTML-based, then CSS makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a print media specific css to format the html just for the printer. That way you can have styles to make it just a perfect as required. An example of how to create such a style sheet is at https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/